# jquery custom plugin and all links

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Lets say I have links like this

```
<a href="/like/1" class="like">Like</a>
<a href="/like/2" class="like">Like</a>
```

I am writing a jquery plugin to ajaxify the links:

```
"use strict";

define(['jquery'], function($) {
    $.fn.like_link = function(options){
        var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.like_link.defaults, options);
        var me = this;

        //attach ajax
        this.click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.get(me.attr('href'), function(result){
                if (result == 'like'){
                    me.text(opts.liked_text);
                }else{
                    me.text(opts.like_text);
                }
            });
        });

        return me;
    }

    $.fn.like_link.defaults = {
        like_text: 'Like',
        liked_text: 'Unlike',
    }
});
```

and use the plugin like:

```
"use strict";

require(['jquery', 'likes/likes'], function($, _) {
    $('.like').like_link();
});
```

But it has unexpected behaviour which when I click on the first link, it actually sends the url of the second link, and changes the text of all links.

My question is how I can make the click event isolated to each link?

Answer (score 0):

After consulting a colleague, manage to target the link properly:

```
"use strict";

define(['jquery'], function($) {
    $.fn.like_link = function(options){
        var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.like_link.defaults, options);
        var me = this;

        //attach ajax
        this.click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var link = $(e.target);
            $.get(link.attr('href'), function(result){
                if (result == 'like'){
                    link.text(opts.liked_text);
                }else{
                    link.text(opts.like_text);
                }
            });
        });

        return me;
    }

    $.fn.like_link.defaults = {
        like_text: 'Like',
        liked_text: 'Unlike',
    }
});
```